# Finding the mouseevents wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, events

My question is very general, I'm making a project and referenced two projects(graphsharp and wpfextensions). These are helping me to create graphs.

When I created my graph for example I can easily drag the vertexes or move the graph by clicking the empty space in screen etc..

But I do not know what is happening in background, for multitouch capabilities, I need to find what is going on when a mouse event raised.

Therefore my question is how to find these events and methods in a lot of source files ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question does really general and fuzzy but probably some tool like Snoop http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ will help you (here you can take a look how it works and looks  http://blois.us/Snoop/). There is "Events" tab for selected part of UI of your application where you can investigate all the way of Event through a visual tree and see who (which control) has handled this event. Then you should check the control that handled this event and see if it's something you are looking for.